# How to create the single contact folder to show receive and send SMS of that contact in the Inbox using kotlin/android.?

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

I have created SMS app but there is a problem.I want to bind the receiving SMS from the same contact in that contact folder created in Inbox,like in whatsapp ,Simple SMS app,but I do not understand how to do this.Can someone help me in this.
Right now my Inbox Activity showing contacts and SMS in this way.
[image: Actual inbox]
I have searched a lot but found nothing.
**Inbox Activity**

```
    class InBox : AppCompatActivity() {

    //private var load: ProgressBar  = this.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1)
    private val requestContactSms: Int = 3
    private val requestReceiveSms: Int = 1
    private val requestReadSms: Int = 2

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.readsms)


        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) !=
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS),
                requestContactSms
            )
        } else {
            refreshSmsInbox()

        }
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS) !=
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS, android.Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS),
                requestReceiveSms
            )
        }

    }


    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        if (requestCode == requestReadSms && requestCode == requestContactSms) refreshSmsInbox()
    }

    @SuppressLint("Recycle", "SimpleDateFormat")
    private fun refreshSmsInbox() {

            try {


                val smsList = ArrayList<SmsData>()
                val cursor = contentResolver.query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"),null,null,null,null)
                cursor?.let{
                    if(it!!.moveToFirst()){
                        val nameID = it.getColumnIndex("address")
                        val messageID = it.getColumnIndex("body")
                        val dateID = it.getColumnIndex("date")

                        do{
                            val dateString = it.getString(dateID)
                            val sms = SmsData(getContactName(this,it.getString(nameID!!.toInt()).toString()),it.getString(messageID),Date(dateString.toLong()).toString())
                            smsList.add(sms)
                        }while (it.moveToNext())
                    }
                    it.close()
                }
                val  adapter = ListAdapter(this, smsList)
                sms_list_view.adapter = adapter


    } catch (ex: Exception) {
                if (this != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, ex.localizedMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }

    }
 @SuppressLint("Recycle")
        fun getContactName(context: Context, phoneNumber: String): String? {
            var contactName: String = phoneNumber
            val uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber))
            val cursor = context.contentResolver.query(uri, arrayOf(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME), null, null, null)
            cursor?.let {
                if (it.moveToFirst()) {
                    contactName = it.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME))
                }
                it.close()
            }
            Log.d("Inbox","contactName $contactName for $phoneNumber")
            return contactName;
        }

}
```

**ListAdapter**

```
@Suppress("DEPRECATION")
class ListAdapter (val context: Context, val list : ArrayList<SmsData>): BaseAdapter(){
    @SuppressLint("ViewHolder", "SimpleDateFormat")
    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {

        val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.rowlayout,parent,false)

        /*view.clickable.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity1::class.java)

            startActivity(intent)
        }*/
        list[position].senderName?.let{
            view.sender.text = it.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()
        }

        view.sms_sender.text = list[position].senderName

        view.sms_message.text = list[position].message

        view.sms_date.text = list[position].date

        view.clickable.setOnClickListener { View ->

            val intent = Intent(context,MainActivity1::class.java)
                    context.startActivity(intent)
        }

        return  view


    }

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Any {
        return list[position]
    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return position.toLong()
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
       return list.size
    }
}
```

**Read SMS XML FIle**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ListView

            android:id="@+id/sms_list_view"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="6"
            tools:ignore="Suspicious0dp"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

**Row_layout XML File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"

              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:padding="10dp">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/sender"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circle"
            android:textColor="#F5F0F1"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:id="@+id/clickable"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:orientation="vertical" tools:ignore="RedundantNamespace">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/sms_sender"

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/sms_message"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/sms_date"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="10sp" tools:ignore="SmallSp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Expected**

[image: Required inbox]

**Actual**

Image[image: Actual inbox]

Comment: Nobody knows the answer..?

Comment: @Tamir do you know the answer..?